# NetBeans 19 Java 17 Remote Debugging Raspberry Pi Not Working Without Nashorn

Tags: netbeans, raspberry-pi, windows-10, java-17, nashorn

I'm trying to upgrade a development environment from NetBeans 12.6 to 19 and Java 11 to 17 on Windows 10.  This environment supports an application targeted to both Windows and Raspberry Pi OS.

After upgrading Java and NetBeans, remote debugging on the Raspberry Pi from Windows (breakpoints, etc.) no longer works.  Running the application remotely on the Raspberry Pi from Windows does still work.

When I attempt a debugging action in NetBeans with the Raspberry Pi platform and configuration selected, I receive the following message:

"Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself. GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option."

I understand that Nashorn was remoted in Java 15.  What I don't understand is what to do about it.

I assume NetBeans is looking for a Nashorn replacement on the Windows system hosting NetBeans and not the Raspberry Pi, but I am not completely certain.

This NetBeans project uses Ant.  I read that upgrading Ant to the latest version (from 1.10.8 to 1.10 14) might resolve this issue, but that did not work.  I also tried installing GraalVM on Windows 10 and enabling options --experimental-options --js.nashorn-compat=true in NetBeans.  That also did not work.

My goal is NetBeans 19 and Java 17 on Windows 10 with the ability to both run and debug on both Windows 10 and Raspberry Pi OS.  Earlier versions of NetBeans and Java made this very easy.

I am not committed to Ant but, as far as I can tell, Maven and Gradle do not provide a similar remote run / debug capability.  But I'm open to switching to a different build system if that resolves my issue.  I'm even willing to consider switching to a different IDE, if necessary.

If you have information that would help me, please be as specific as you can.  My expertise is in the application domain and the Java language, not NetBeans, Nashorn, etc.

Comment: Nashorn was deprecated in JDK 11, and removed in JDK 15. So your workaround would be to use a JDK < 15 if possible. The issue with Ant (_"Java 15 has removed Nashorn..."_) has been bug reported, with no resolution yet. See [Unable to start remote debugging due to error "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript" #5977](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5977).

Comment: I have no ideas on switching to GraalVM, but there is some generic (i.e. Not specific to NetBeans) documentation on that (which you may have already seen):  [Migration Guide from Nashorn to GraalVM JavaScript](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/js/NashornMigrationGuide/)

Comment: I had previously reviewed Apache NetBeans issue #5977.  The statement at the bottom of that issue regarding Ant 1.10.8 (bundled with NetBeans 19) being incompatible with Java 17 led me to upgrade Ant to 1.10.14.  But that did not resolve anything for me.

Comment: I had already found generic documentation on GraalVM and think I installed it properly.  I believe NetBeans was using GraalVM because I noted some other features of NetBeans were broken until I added the --experimental-options and --js.nashorn-compat=true options.  But I have not found any specific instructions on installing and configuring GraalVM specifically for NetBeans.

Comment: I will probably step back to NetBeans 19 with Java 11 and hope that issue #5977 gets resolved at some point in the future.  NetBeans 19 is officially supported on Java 11, 17 and 20.  I am already running my application on Java 17 on the Raspberry Pi,, and remote debugging previously worked with NetBeans 12.6 with Java 11 on Windows and Java 17 on the Pi.  Hopefully the upgrade to NetBeans 19 won't impact that.

Comment: OK. While regressing to JDK 11 is not ideal, if it works it's better than being stuck. And if that approach works please consider posting an answer to your own question, and accepting it. Having an actual answer is more helpful to the community than a resolution buried in the comments. NetBeans 19 with JDK 11 should be a safe and reliable combination, the only issue being you obviously can't use any Java features added since JDK 11.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer to my own question that is, at best, a poor answer.  I'm continuing to use NetBeans 19, but I've reverted to Java 11.

In doing this I initially had a different problem with remote debugging that was previously documented at https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5979 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1425 .

The solution posted in issue #1425, to add a definition for debug-args-line to build.xml, did resolve that problem for me in NetBeans 19 on Windows 10.

So I can once again both run and debug my application on both Windows 10 and Raspberry Pi OS.  But I must use Java 11 (or presumably any Java < 15 with Nashorn) to achieve that.

Comment: I'm not trying to turn you away from NetBeans, but have you considered using Intellij IDEA instead for your Win/Pi application? The are plenty of articles and YouTube videos on that approach, and getting Intellij IDEA running on Pi. For example, see [Installing IntelliJ IDE On Raspberry Pi (Java / Raspberry Pi)](https://geektechstuff.com/2019/06/08/installing-intellij-ide-on-raspberry-pi-java-raspberry-pi/), especially the comments at the end of that article.